# Wordpress posts & pages using the wrong index.php

Tags: wordpress

I've updated the main page for my site (http://www.goldfinchnj.com) to show the most recent posts from a wordpress site (http://www.goldfinchnj.com/news) The main page is mostly HTML, but I had to make it a .php file so it would pull in the 3 most recent posts.

The problem is all the pages & posts on the wordpress site seem to be using the index.php file from the root directory (the index for the main page).

Before this issue started, I changed the directory of the wordpress install. It was news.goldfinchnj.com, but I wanted it to be goldfinch.com/news.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How have you changed the directory? Have you updated all links in the database? Manually or you used search and replace plugin? Do you host wp on apache server? Do you have correct index.php in news subfolder and correct .htaccess?

Comment: I downloaded the entire install directory and uploaded it to the new directory via ftp. Then I changed the URL in the wordpress settings. I didn't make any changes to the database. I followed the instructions for Method II here https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: My web host is 1and1, I'm not sure if it's an apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Took another look at the .htaccess and had to update the path for the IfModule mod_rewrite.c